# Asymptotic behavior of a recurrence sequence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

I am solving this question:

Let $x_0=1$ and $$x_{n+1}=\log\left(\dfrac{e^{x_n}-1}{x_n}\right)$$
Compute the limit :$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2^nx_n$$
The answer is NOT 1 because

it is easy to find that $$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=\dfrac{1}{x_{n}}\log\left(\dfrac{e^{x_n}-1}{x_n}\right)>\dfrac{1}{2}$$ because $x_{n}\downarrow 0$. So $2^{n+1}x_{n+1}>2^nx_{n}>1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Using methods of complex analysis, I found the answer equals $f(1)$ where $f(x)$ is analytic function with $f(0)=0$ and satisfies the equation:$$f\left(\log\left(\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}\right)\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}f(x)$$
But I met difficulty solving this equation.
My questions are:

1. Is there a closed form of the solution?If not, what is its numerical solution?
2. Is there another method to estimate the asymptotic behavior of $x_n$?

Comment: I *suppose* that $\log(x_n)$ is *almost* linear with respect to $n$

Comment: One problem is that if $f(x)$ is a solution of the functional equation, then $cf(x)$ is also a solution for any constant $c$. Thus, you also need to specify $f'(1).$ Given that, the power series expansion is uniquely determined.

Comment: It seems to be close to $ 1.186401367185$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.